# Crontab is Not Running Crons

Tags: php, vps, cron

I have crontab setup on my CentOS VPS and it is not running...

Here's the cron file:

```
* * * * * php -f /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/1min.php
* * * * * php -f /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/1minemail.php
*/15 * * * * php -f /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/15min.php
*/30 * * * * php -f /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/30min.php
0 */1 * * * php -f /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/hourly.php
0 0 */1 * * php -f /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/daily.php
0 0 */7 * * php -f /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/weekly.php
0 0 */30 * * php -f /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/bimonthly.php
0 0 * * * php -f /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/clearreport.php
```

I've also tried another variation of that:

```
* * * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/1min.php
* * * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/1minemail.php
*/15 * * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/15min.php
*/30 * * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/30min.php
0 */1 * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/hourly.php
0 0 */1 * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/daily.php
0 0 */7 * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/weekly.php
0 0 */30 * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/bimonthly.php
0 0 * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/clearreport.php

* * * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/1min.php
* * * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/1minemail.php
*/15 * * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/15min.php
*/30 * * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/30min.php
0 */1 * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/hourly.php
0 0 */1 * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/daily.php
0 0 */7 * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/weekly.php
0 0 */30 * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/bimonthly.php
0 0 * * * php -q /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/pingrglobe_com/crons/clearreport.php
```

I am able to run the files from my web browser, but not from crontab.

Comment: Is `crond` running?

Comment: I think that might have been the issue, I'll let you know shortly if you're a legend! xD

Comment: I <3 you!!
Please post that as the answer, and I will mark it answered.

Comment: Done! Glad to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your `crond` is running. Also make sure (and test this) that it will start on boot properly.

Comment: Can't accept for another 9 minutes, I will do it in 9. :)